# Python . Подскажите, как упростить код генератора паролей

Tags: python, python-3.x, генераторы

```
# Генератор паролей
# Пароль должен быть не меньше 8 символов
# должен содержать как минимум одну заглавную букву
# должен содержать как минимум одну строчную букву
# должен содержать как минимум одну цифру
# должен содержать как минимум один спец-символ (!&? и прочие)
# а еще он не должен содержать некоторые символы, чтобы не поломать bash-скрипты

import random
import string

password = []
forbidden = ['+', '-', ',', '`', '^']  # запрещенные символы

lis_uppercase = []                     # создание списков из строк ascii
for f in string.ascii_uppercase:
    lis_uppercase.append(f)

lis_lowercase = []
for f in string.ascii_lowercase:
    lis_lowercase.append(f)

lis_octdigits = []
for f in string.octdigits:
    lis_octdigits.append(f)

lis_punctuation = []
for f in string.punctuation:
    lis_punctuation.append(f)
for f in forbidden:                    # удаление запрещенных символов из списка
    lis_punctuation.remove(f)

password.append(random.choice(lis_uppercase))  # по одному элементу с каждого списка,
password.append(random.choice(lis_lowercase))  # всего списков 4
password.append(random.choice(lis_octdigits))
password.append(random.choice(lis_punctuation))

length = int(input('Length: '))  # ввод длины пароля
while length <= 0 or length > 15:
    print('Ошибка ввода')
    length = int(input('Length: '))

lis_all = lis_uppercase + lis_lowercase + lis_octdigits + lis_punctuation  # обьединяем списки

for f in range(length - 4):  # от длины вычитаем количество списков(т.е. 4 элемента)
    length -= 1
    password.append(random.choice(lis_all))  # добавляем остальные символы
    if length == 0:
        break

password = ''.join(password)
print(password)
```

Comment: в принципе, должно работать. Непонятно, зачем if с break. И в конце стоит перемешать список

Comment: Да и списки можно собирать `list(ascii_uppercase)`

Comment: Насчет перемешать- да, забыл добавить. Насчет if с break действительно, самому только что дошло

Comment: да и работать будет прям  так  - `random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)` - строка тоже итерируемый объект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решение в лоб, правда не очень эффективное, потому что пароль может генерироваться в течении нескольких проходов, зато самое короткое решение, а при большой длине пароля кол-во проходов будет минимальным:

```
import random

password = ''

while True:
    dictionary = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!&?'

    password = ''.join(random.choices(dictionary, k=random.randint(8, 16)))

    if any(l.isdigit() for l in password) and any(l.isupper() for l in password) and any(l.islower() for l in password) and any(l in '!&?' for l in password):
        break

print(password)
```

А вот так выглядит однопроходный алгоритм:

```
import random

dictionary = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!&?'
dictionaries = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '0123456789', '!&?']

password = [random.choice(d) for d in dictionaries] + random.choices(dictionary, k=random.randint(8, 16) - 4)
random.shuffle(password)
password = ''.join(password)

print(password)
```

ну или вот так, чтобы избавиться от дублирования словарей:

```
import random

dictionaries = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '0123456789', '!&?']

password = [random.choice(d) for d in dictionaries] + random.choices(''.join(dictionaries), k=random.randint(8, 16) - 4)
random.shuffle(password)
password = ''.join(password)

print(password)
```

Comment: Интересно получилось, что в ответе с избавлением от дублирования словарей ты по сути удалил dictionarry и код продолжил работать будто ничего не произошло. И вот мои 40 строк вместились в 6. Упростил так упростил)

Comment: потому что кодом `''.join(dictionaries)` я 4 словаря соединил в 1 и выбирал символы из него, а 4 отдельных словаря мне нужны были, чтобы выбрать сначала по 1 необходимому символу из этих 4 словарей

Comment: Вроде врубился. Обьясни еще пж более подробно момент с k=random.randint

Comment: `random.choices` позволяет сгенерировать не 1 случайное значение из словаря как `random.choice`, а целую последовательность размером `k=size`, поскольку обязательные 4 символа были сгенерированы ранее, то осталось сгенерировать `размер пароля - 4`, а размер пароля - это случайное число от 8 до 12 (не знаю сколько оно вам нужно было изначально, просто поставил 8-12), а последующая функция `random.shuffle` перемешивает в случайном порядке полученный набор символов - вот и получили случайный пароль

Comment: окей, а можно ли заменить k=size на random.sample(list, number)

Comment: да меняйте на что хотите, это же ничего не ограничено, только код будет `k=random.sample(list, number)-4`, а можете написать `k=10-4` и у вас пароль будет из 10 символов (опять напомню, что `-4` надо поскольку 4 символа уже сгенерированы были ранее)

Comment: Все оказалось намного проще. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

```
import random, string

forbidden = set('+-,`^')  # запрещенные символы
special_symbols = set(string.punctuation) - forbidden

password_len = 10
password = []
all_symbols = set()
for seq in (string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase, string.digits, special_symbols):
    password.append(random.choice(list(seq)))
    all_symbols.update(seq)

password.extend(random.choices(list(all_symbols), k=password_len-4))
random.shuffle(password)
password = ''.join(password)
print(password)
```

Comment: Вроде понял, спасибо. Не могу найти строку, где с вывода удаляются запрещенные символы.